# php mail() "Could not find domain on our servers"

Tags: php

I'm working on a windows based server and I am wondering why a server would return this error message when using the mail() function:

```
Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 554 Invalid From address:
xxxxx@MyDomain.com. Could not find domain MyDomain.com on our servers.
The email From address must be of type any_valid_name@yourdomain.com in 
\\web-123win\winpackage22\MyDomain\web\content\mail.php on line 16
```

I mean, isn't the mail() function supposed to send emails to whatever domain we want?

Can you help me in the understanding of this message? thanks

Comment: Your error messages says 'From address', not 'To address'. Perhaps your email server software only allows you to send emails from a list of preconfigured domains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since spam become the 99% of all e-mail traffic most mail servers no longer accept all mail they're handed. Instead, they only accept messages from these categories:

- Incoming mail for their users
- Outcoming mail from their users

Your mail appears to belong to the second category so you must provide a proof of identify so they know you're allowed to user their mail system. The details depend on the mail provider but you're normally required to provide a username and password.

Said that, `mail()` function does not implement authentication so you need to use a third-party package like PHPMailer or Swift Mailer.